# Firestore get all fields from a single document pure JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get **all** fields from a firestore document, and add the fieldnames to an array?

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

I've tried:

```js
db.collection('list').where('id','==',id).get(snapshot =>{
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
    var fields = doc.get([No idea what to put here]);
  })
})
```

Comment: @DougStevenson Done - it's more of a matter of that I have no idea how to do it and can't find a way to anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[doc.data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) will return a regular JavaScript object with properties and values the same as the fields and values in the document.  You can then use one of the usual JavaScript methods (such as [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) to get all the properties of that object.

```
var fields = Object.keys(doc.data())
```